# C++ Hangman program check if work function

Tags: c++

This is the program i have so far it compiles but outputs are wrong. I'm trying to fix this function that compares two arrays and returns true if they are equal and false if not.

```
bool CheckWon ( char selectedWord[], char gameBoard[] )
{
    bool checkWon = false;
    int length = strlen(selectedWord);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    if ( strcmp( gameBoard[i], selectedWord[i] ) == 0)
        checkWon = true;

    return checkWon;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: We need some report/description of what has gone wrong, and preferably what platform/compiler you are working with.

Comment: If there's a flaw in the logic, surely it's in just one function, right? Have a look with a debugger, see what values everything has, see what doesn't work the way you expect it to!

Comment: Like Jefromi says, step through with a debugger.  If you designed the code, you shouldn't have any difficulty spotting what's wrong.  (Not true in general, but this is a simple single-threaded case)

Comment: The program runs but I can't get the correct out put from, the function void DisplayGuesses(); the function has to out put the previous guess a user have used. the input is previousGuesses[] array that has a index of 26, if a player has used that letter the value was set to a 1 in a previous called function CorrectGuess();

Comment: you should at least be able to narrow down the problem on your own before approaching the community. to just submit your whole pile of code is a bit rude.

Comment: For real, we have lives too :(

Comment: `cout << "You lose lol"<<endl;`, the code of a true programmer

Comment: @realcoolguy: I'll let the community decide on deletion, since there's an answer with significant upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

Hm, just by virtue of scrolling all the way to the bottom by habit... is your problem in CheckWon? You can't compare character arrays like that; you need to compare them character-by-character, or since you're using C++, upgrade to std::string so that you *can* test equality.

For proof, just try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char a[] = "Hello";
    char b[] = "Hello";
    if (a == b) {
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "not equal" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your edited code (just the CheckWon function): are selectedWord and gameBoard both null-terminated char arrays? If so, you can rewrite this function as:

```
bool CheckWon ( char selectedWord[], char gameBoard[] )
{
    return strcmp(gameBoard, selectedWord) == 0;
}
```

<strike>(Your code should be functionally equivalent to this, although much less efficient.)</strike>

But since you say that your code is giving wrong answers, I suspect that this isn't the case. If that's true, then you need to pass the lengths of the arrays as additional args and rewrite your logic a bit. (I suggest starting by testing that the lengths of the arrays are equal.)

**Edit:** I think that the problem with your code is that it will return true if the two arguments end with the same suffix (such as `CheckWon("foo", "boo");`)